# How to fetch value of an enum present in an inner class through Reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, enums, inner-classes

Hello all I am trying to access the value of an enum present in an inner class as shown below ,but what I am getting is not the value but the key. The need of my application is I have to access this value through reflection.

```
public class Test{
 static class TwelveByTwentyFour {
     public static enum BET_TYPE_NAME {
         Direct12(12),AllOdd(12),AllEven(12), First12(12), Last12(12);

    private int value;
    BET_TYPE_NAME(int value){
                this.value = value;
            }

            public  int getValue() {
                return value;
            }
            public void setValue(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
    }

 }
 public static String getBetTypeLength(String gameName,String betType) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException{
        return Class.forName(Test.class.getCanonicalName()+"$"+gameName+"$"+"BET_TYPE_NAME").getDeclaredField(betType).get(null).toString();
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    System.out.println(getBetTypeLength("TwelveByTwentyFour", "AllEven"));
}
```

}

On doing this I am getting `"AllEven"` as output instead of `"12"`. Can anyone please help me by telling me that how can I get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `BET_TYPE_NAME.AllEven.toString()` and it is implemented in the parent `Enum` class to return the same value as `BET_TYPE_NAME.AllEven.name()`, thus you get `"AllEven"`.

To get `"12"`, you either need to override the `toString()` inside the `BET_TYPE_NAME` enum like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.value;
}
```

Or cast the result of `Field.get(null)` to the enum `BET_TYPE_NAME` and call `getValue()` on it:

```
return Integer.toString(((TwelveByTwentyFour.BET_TYPE_NAME)
        Class.forName(Test.class.getCanonicalName()+"$"+gameName+"$"+"BET_TYPE_NAME")
                .getDeclaredField(betType).get(null)).getValue());
```

BTW, the enum should never have a setter and the `value` should always be **final** — enum constants are shared singletons.